# Get substring in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to get a substring in SQL Server from last sequence of a split on dot (`.`).

I have a column which contains file names such as `hello.exe`, and I want to find the extension of the file exactly as `Path.GetExtension("filename")` does in C#.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx) along with [`substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and [`charindex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to get what you're looking for:

```
select
    reverse(substring(reverse(filename), 1, 
        charindex('.', reverse(filename))-1)) as FileExt
from
    mytable
```

This holds up, even if you have multiple `.` in your file (e.g.-`hello.world.exe` will return `exe`).

So I was playing around a bit with this, and this is another way (only one call to `reverse`):

```
select 
    SUBSTRING(filename, 
        LEN(filename)-(CHARINDEX('.', reverse(filename))-2), 8000) as FileExt
from
    mytable
```

This calculates 10,000,000 rows in 25 seconds versus 29 seconds for the former method.

Comment: +1 good call ! I was wondering if there way any easy way to deal with multiple '.' in the file name, without resorting to messy character counting and parsing - well done!

Comment: charindex('.', reverse(filename))-1 fails when there is no dot in filename. used charindex('.', reverse(filename))

Comment: in Mysql you can use SUBSTRING_INDEX, for example: SUBSTRING_INDEX(file_name, '.', -1), maybe there is something similar to sql-server

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @originalstring VARCHAR(100)
SET @originalstring = 'hello.exe'

DECLARE @extension VARCHAR(50)

SET @extension = SUBSTRING(@originalstring, CHARINDEX('.', @originalstring) + 1, 999)

SELECT @extension
```

That should do it, I hope! This works as long as you only have a single '.' in your file name - separating the file name from the extension.

Marc

Comment: This is a good answer IF you are 100% sure there is only one period (Fullstop) in the originalstring variable. Otherwise, the approved is better.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT RIGHT(
             'C:\SomeRandomFile\Filename.dat',
             CHARINDEX(
                       '.',
                       REVERSE(
                               'C:\SomeRandomFile\Filename.dat'
                              ),
                       0)
              -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as accepted answer, but I've added a condition to avoid error when `filename` is null or when `filename` has no extension (no point):

```
select
    reverse(substring(reverse(filename), 1, 
        charindex('.', reverse(filename))-1)) as FileExt
from
    mytable
where 
    filename is not null
and charindex('.',filename) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL request adressed most of the edge cases in my weird database where many files didn't have extensions.

```
select distinct reverse(left(reverse(fileNameWithExtension), charindex('.', reverse(fileNameWithExtension)) - 1))
from myTable
where charindex('.', reverse(fileNameWithExtension)) - 1 > 0 and charindex('.', reverse(fileNameWithExtension)) - 1 < 7 and fileNameWithExtension is not null
```