# Get extension of a file using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get substring in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226789/get-substring-in-sql-server)

Let's say I have `MyImage.png` or `MyDoc.doc`, etc in a column in a database table.

How can I only get the file extension?

Comment: Select substring LIKE with a regexp :-) and extract

Answer (score 51, accepted):

try this:

```sql
declare @str varchar(20)='MyDoc.doc';
select reverse(left(reverse(@str),charindex('.',reverse(@str))-1))
```

###[SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6463)

Comment: Fails if @str does not contain a '.'

Comment: Good answer, but not supporting stripping away querysrings, like "index.html?id=1". But besides that, good answer :-)

Comment: Add a check to check if '.' is present in the filename else return the filename itself

`declare @str varchar(20)='MyDocdoc';
select CASE WHEN charindex('.',@str) > 0 THEN reverse(left(reverse(@str),charindex('.',reverse(@str))-1)) ELSE @str END`

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT parsename(filename,1) FROM yourTable
```

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db40b/1)

Comment: A period is valid in a file name. This won't work if your file name has more than 3 periods. This.File.Name.Will.Break.txt

Comment: But it works if there is no more than two periods in file name. `This.Will.Work.txt`.

Answer (score 5):

With string functions:

```sql
SELECT Extension =
   Right([Name],
        CHARINDEX('.',
                  REVERSE([Name]))-1)
FROM dbo.Files
```

[**SQL fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c4cb/3/0)

Comment: This breaks on filenames without extension: `Invalid length parameter passed to the right function.`

Answer (score 4):

```sql
SELECT RIGHT('myFile.txt', 
               CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE('myFile.txt'))-1) AS 'File Extension'
```

Documentation: [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx), [RIGHT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx), [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx), [REVERSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx)

Comment: It seems the last edit is a dup of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13508538/1657465) Tim gave

Answer (score 3):

```sql
declare @str varchar(20)='MyDoc.doc'
select reverse(left(reverse(@str),CHARINDEX('.',reverse(@str))-1))
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6479)

Comment: i updated the query pls check

Comment: Failing,  declare @str varchar(20)='2012_11_22 11_25_47_260.jpg';
select RIGHT(@str,(len(@str)-CHARINDEX('.',@str)))

Comment: NOt working, Please test it throughly

Comment: try the fiddle demo its working

Comment: this ended up a complete duplicate of the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13508412/1026