# Keep end of url in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that gives back a string that reads like `//path1/path2/item.itm`, `//path1/path3/item.itm` or `//path4/path5/item.itm` what I would like to do is have it just return something like `/path2/item.itm` I know that there is a replace in sql along the lines of `REPLACE(String, ‘//path1’, ‘’)` but this wont work since the string is not consistent in all entries. I cant do this in the code because I may need to put the values back in.

If I were to do this in code (which I cant do) it would be something along the lines of

```
string = string.Remove(string.LastIndexOf('/'),
                       string.Length - string.LastIndexOf('/'));
```

but I have no idea how to do this in SQL or any idea if it can be done.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226789/get-substring-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
declare @str varchar(100) = '//path1/path2/item.itm'
select SUBSTRING(@str, PATINDEX('%[^/]/%', @str) + 1, LEN(@str) - PATINDEX('%[^/]/%', @str))
```

or, if you know max length of your strings (I assume), says max = 8000, you can use this:

```
select SUBSTRING(@str, PATINDEX('%[^/]/%', @str) + 1, 8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be faster than PATINDEX() but you could reverse the string take up to the `/` then reverse it again something like this:

```
  SELECT  REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(path),CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(path))))
```

nb, I didn't test so I might have a typo.